# PHP different one way hashes for password security

Tags: php, security, md5, sha1, password-protection

I was wondering to hash the password in PHP using different methods available and the combination of them for more and more security.
  I was wondering if this would work..?

```
$pass = "***";
$salt = "!@)#%%@(#&@_!R151";
$pass = sha1($pass.$salt);
$pass = md5($pass);
```

Comment: I don't think `md5()`-ing a `sha1()` hash is a good idea...

Comment: Yes, this would work. But make sure that the salt is unique for each password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than that, you can **use a stronger hashing algorithm** like **`sha512`** with combination of a strong salt and `UserID`: Do it like this:

```
 echo hash('sha512', 'MyPassword' . $StrongSalt . $UserID);
```

SHA512 is actually SHA-2 for which there are no collisions found. See at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha512).

Comment: Ummm, won't that defeat the point?  Since `microtime()` is not reproducible, you just created a hash that you can't verify (unless you store it somewhere)...

Comment: @ircmaxell, Ohh yes, I just forgot that part. Thanks for reminding. Fixed it :)

Comment: The salt should be random or, if possible, unique for each entry & be stored with the password in raw, so you can compare the hash later. Salts purpose is to avoid rainbow table attacks or to avoid revealing two users having the same password. I do not believe there is such a thing as a "strong salt" as it's in raw text anyways, the strength relies in the hashing algo as even a small change in the input string should create a wildly different output hash.

Comment: @Kilnky, by appending `$UserID`, it makes the sale unique for every user.

Comment: True, but what is the point of $StrongSalt ? A unique salt(e.g. userId) is about as strong as you're going to get.

Comment: I think whirlpool is pretty elite, as far as hashes go. It's my favorite for some reason, and is supported by the PHP `hash` function.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Combinations do not add any security.
Actually you made it less secure. Theoretically, but anyway.

I have a feeling that hashing issues are way overestimated.
Nobody concerns in any other security issue but everyone anxious to make a hash unbreakable in a billion years. Relax, buddy. There are thousands other ways to break your app.

Comment: You can add security to your password using other ways like splitting the hashed password and storing it somewhere else. (saw this technique in gallery2)

Comment: @sheeks the only question - do you really need it?

Comment: No. :) just sharing. might be useful to him.

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding a salt is enough, but if you want more maybe do:

```
sha1($salt. sha1($salt. $pass));
```

and let `$salt` contain some non-printed chars, arbitrary binary data or anything like that.

Again, I guess this won't add much since implementation I saw only add $salt, but why not more security for the coming ages : )

Answer (score 0):

Your passwords will most likely, never be 100% secure.

Try looking at a [nonce.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) Which should be generated for each individual user.

Comment: you mean each salt should be a nonce?

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you are going to do this, don't just MD5 the result:

```
$pass = "***";
$salt = "!@)#%%@(#&@_!R151";
$pass = sha1($pass.$salt);
$pass = md5($pass);
```

Instead, run md5 on the result and the inputs...

```
$pass = "***";
$salt = "!@)#%%@(#&@_!R151";
$tmp = sha1($pass.$salt);
$pass = md5($tmp . $pass . $salt);
```

The reason is that if you do `md5(sha1())`, you're basically increasing the chances of collision.  The reason is that all `sha1` collisions would automatically be collisions in the `md5` call (hence it's a superset of the collisions).  By re-entering the password and salt, you're preventing that from happening, and hence creating a "stronger" hash rather than a weaker one...

Comment: If I understand these things correctly, when I brute force this pass, first MD5 collision will let me in, no matter it's arguments. Where I am wrong?

Comment: @Col: Yes, the first `md5` collision will let you in.  That's always the case.  But if you just do `md5(sha1(stuff))`, you can find either a `md5` collision **OR** a `sha1` collision.  Either will let you in fine.  Whereas if you do `md5(sha1(stuff) . stuff)`, you're eliminating that issue.  As for why to hash multiple times, you can read [more about it in this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time/3559497#3559497)...  Oh, and I'm not trying to suggest to use this method (`md5(sha1())`), only **IF** it's used...

Comment: This odd behavior again. Why to answer at all if you do not suggest your answer yourself? I can't stand it.

Comment: @Col: I'm saying that IF he's going to do it in the first place, he may as well do it right.  I wouldn't do it personally (I'd much rather do a number of rounds of `sha512`), but that doesn't mean it's "bad" to do.  The answer that I gave pointed out a fundamental flaw (albeit a small one) in the solution he provided...