# How to generate a good salt - Is my function secure enough?

Tags: php, security, salt

Here's the function I'm using to generate random salts:

```
function generateRandomString($nbLetters){
    $randString="";
    $charUniverse="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    for($i=0; $i<$nbLetters; $i++){
       $randInt=rand(0,61);
        $randChar=$charUniverse[$randInt];
        $randString=$randomString.$randChar;
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

This is for a non commercial website.  It's only used to generate the salt (to be stored in the db and used along with the user submitted pw for hashing).

Is this appropriate?  Should I use a larger subset of characters, and if so is there an easy way to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you are hashing passwords, you should use a modern hashing algorithm that does not require you to generate your own salt. Using weak hashing algorithms presents a danger to both you and your users. My original answer was written eight years ago. Times have changed, and password hashing is a lot easier now.

You should *always* use built in functions to hash/check passwords. Using your own algorithms at any point introduces a huge amount of unnecessary risk.

For PHP, consider using [password_hash()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), with the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` algorithm. There is no need to provide your own salt.

Below is my original answer, for posterity:

---

> **Warning**: The following implementation does not produce an unpredictable salt, as per the documentation for [uniqid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

From the [php sha1 page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php):

```
$salt = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
```

This looks simpler, and more effective (since each is unique) than what you have proposed.

Answer (score 18):

If you're on Linux, `/dev/urandom` is probably your best source of randomness. It's supplied by the OS itself, so it's guaranteed to be much more reliable than any PHP built-in function.

```
$fp = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
$randomString = fread($fp, 32);
fclose($fp);
```

This will give you 32 bytes of random blob. You'll probably want to pass this through something like `base64_encode()` to make it legible. No need to juggle characters yourself.

**Edit 2014:** In PHP 5.3 and above, `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is the easiest way to get a bunch of random bytes. On *nix systems, it uses `/dev/urandom` behind the scenes. On Windows systems, it uses a different algorithm that is built into the OpenSSL library.

Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26206

Related: [should i use urandom or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089516)

Comment: I agree with this.  The OP is using a non cryptographic secure pseudorandom generator.  I'd only add that the salt can be stored as a binary in the DB to reduce base64 encode/decode latency since the hash should be transparent to the authentication login.  Also, if the server is IIS/Win32 the mcrypt_create_iv() function, if available, will pool the win32 cryptoAPI should you need good random bits in that scenario and not want to deal with COM interfacing (CAPICOM or whatever).  Since the OP asked about a random salt I think @kijin answer is the best solution.

Comment: +1 this is the best answer on this page,  Although i would not do a base64_encode.  Keep in mind all message digest functions are binary safe, and you want a full byte salt,  alpha-numeric rainbow tables are very common,  but base256 rainbowtables are unheard of.

Comment: @Rook Sure, you can pass any binary string to a hash function. But the salt is usually also stored along with the hash. (How else are you going to compare the hash against a password later?) See, most people tend to store the whole thing in a text column in a database such as MySQL. Text columns don't accept arbitrary binary, so you must _either_ turn it into a blob column _or_ use something like base64. It just makes your salt longer; the cryptographical strength is the same.

Comment: @kijin i see what you are saying.  But actually if you escape the binary prior to insert then it preserves the value. You can even store images in the database,  `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Rook Even if you escape it, blob is the correct data type for binary values such as images. Text columns have a character set attached to them, which can mess up your binary depending on which DBMS you use. I wanted to provide an answer that plays nice with the varchar/text types that are usually assigned to password fields, so I stick to my recommendation that any binary salt should be base64 encoded. If you want to use blob to save some disk space, that's fine.

Comment: @kijin As the top security answerer I say that the most secure answer is the most important.  An alpha numeric table large enough to break a base64 salt would also break large hashed passwords that are unsalted.  That being said,  what is more likely,  a rainbow table that is +256 bytes or that encompasses the entire base 256...  Both are very unlikely,  so I will have a salt of base 256 and 256 bytes long,  such that not even the most powerful government will have enough disk space to store such a table.

Comment: @Rook base64 reduces the amount of randomness _per byte_, but it also increases the total number of bytes. The net effect has no implications for security. In my example above, I used 256 bits (32 bytes) of randomness. base64 encoding will make it 44 bytes long, but the amount of randomness is still 256 bits. You'll need all the atoms in the Universe and then some more to build a storage device big enough to keep all possible combinations of 44 alphanumeric characters. Do the math, you'll see.

Answer (score 8):

[`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is availble in PHP 5.5 and newer. I am surprised to learn it is not mentioned here.

With password_hash() there is no need to generate a salt as the salt is automatically being generated using the bcrypt algorithm -- and therefore no need to make up a set of characters.

Instead, the user-submitted password is compared to the unique password hash stored in the database using password_verify(). Just store Username and Password hash in the user database table, you will then be able to compare it to a user-submitted password using password_verify().

How password hash()'ing works:

The password_hash() function outputs a unique password hash, when storing the string in a database -- it is recommended that the column allows up to 255 characters.

```
$password = "goat";
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Output example (store this in the database)
$2y$10$GBIQaf6gEeU9im8RTKhIgOZ5q5haDA.A5GzocSr5CR.sU8OUsCUwq  <- This hash changes.
$2y$10$7.y.lLyEHKfpxTRnT4HmweDKWojTLo1Ra0hXXlAC4ra1pfneAbj0K
$2y$10$5m8sFNEpJLBfMt/3A0BI5uH4CKep2hiNI1/BnDIG0PpLXpQzIHG8y
```

To verify a hashed password, you use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
$password_enc = password_hash("goat", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
dump(password_verify('goat', $password_enc)); // TRUE
dump(password_verify('fish', $password_enc)); // FALSE
```

If you prefer, salt can be added manually as an option, like so:

```
$password = 'MyPassword';
$salt = 'MySaltThatUsesALongAndImpossibleToRememberSentence+NumbersSuch@7913';
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt'=>$salt]);
// Output: $2y$10$TXlTYWx0VGhhdFVzZXNBT.ApoIjIiwyhEvKC9Ok5qzVcSal7T8CTu  <- This password hash not change.
```

Comment: This answer is good, because it is covering the newest PHP implementation for generating passwords. But it doesn't answer the question on how to generate a good salt (sometimes you explicitly need this, e.g. for other hashing purposes).

Comment: Thanks. Generating a new salt is straight-forward: ```$salt = password_hash("goat", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);``` Answer updated.

Comment: @KristofferBohmann - You do not create a salt this way, the result is the password hash. It would be very wasteful on the cpu to generate salts this way, and the "salts" are not optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `rand(0,61)` with [`mt_rand(0, 61)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and you should be fine (Since `mt_rand` is better at producing random numbers)...

But more important than strength of the salt is the way you hash it.  If you have a great salt routine, but only do `md5($pass.$salt)`, you're throwing away the salt.  I personally recommend stretching the hash... For example:

```
function getSaltedHash($password, $salt) {
    $hash = $password . $salt;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $hash = hash('sha512', $password . $hash . $salt);
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

For more information on hash stretching, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time/3559497#3559497)...

Comment: My function is:function stringHashing($saltedString){$hashedString=hash('sha256',$saltedString);
  return $hashedString;
 }

Comment: @ircmaxell Does this need updating or is this still relevant now?

Answer (score 4):

I would take advice from another answer and use [mt_rand(0, 61)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), because the Mersenne Twister produces better entropy.

Additionally, your function is really two parts: generating random `$nbLetters` digits and encoding that in base62.  This will make things much clearer to a maintenance programmer (maybe you!) who stumbles across it a few years down the road:

```
// In a class somewhere
private $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

private function getBase62Char($num) {
    return $chars[$num];
}

public function generateRandomString($nbLetters){
    $randString="";

    for($i=0; $i < $nbLetters; $i++){
        $randChar = getBase62Char(mt_rand(0,61));
        $randString .= $randChar;
    }

    return $randomString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my method, It uses truly random numbers from atmospheric noise. It is all mixed in with pseudo-random values and strings. Shuffled and hashed. Here is my code: I call it overkill.

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function get_true_random_number($min = 1, $max = 100) {
    $max = ((int) $max >= 1) ? (int) $max : 100;
    $min = ((int) $min < $max) ? (int) $min : 1;
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'PHP',
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    );

    $ch = curl_init('http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min='
        . $min . '&max=' . $max . '&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if(is_numeric($content)) {
        return trim($content);
    } else {
        return rand(-10,127);
    }
}

function generateSalt() {
    $string = generateRandomString(10);
    $int = get_true_random_number(-2,123);
    $shuffled_mixture = str_shuffle(Time().$int.$string);
    return $salt = md5($shuffled_mixture);
}

echo generateSalt();
?>
```

The atmospheric noise is provided by random.org. I have also seen truly random generation from images of lava lamps that are interpreted via hue and location. (Hue is location)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much better way if you have windows and cant do /dev/random.

```
//Key generator
$salt = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128, $secure));
//The variable $secure is given by openssl_random_ps... and it will give a true or false if its tru then it means that the salt is secure for cryptologic.
while(!$secure){
    $salt = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128, $secure));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that a very good salt for example is the user name (if you are talking about pw hashing and the user name doesn't change.)

You don't need to generate anything and don't need to store further data.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but you'd probably want at least to perform a trivial function on the username first. could be as simple as repeating it twice, or adding a character at the end.  while what you suggest is mathematically sound, it could easily be guessed.

Comment: Who cares whether it can be guessed? The purpose of a salt is to prevent using *one* rainbow table for *all* hashes in a DB. And this does it's job.

Comment: Yeah that's right. The salt can even be public, important is that the salt is individual for each password.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple technique:

```
$a = array('a', 'b', ...., 'A', 'B', ..., '9');
shuffle($a);
$salt = substr(implode($a), 0, 2);  // or whatever sized salt is wanted
```

Unlike uniqid() it generates a random result.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTES, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Comment: Base64 encoding can also return the characters '+' and '/', maybe this is not what the OP needs. Then the salt should be created for a specific algorithm with a given length, the length in your example is fix and difficult to predict.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ultimate unique salt you should use a unique value entered and required by the user such as the email or the username, then hashing it using sha1 and then merge it - concatenate -  with the salt value generated by your code.

Another, you have to extend `$charUniverse` by the mean of some special characters such as `@,!#-` etc.