# should i use urandom or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes?

Tags: php, random, salt

I am developing a site in php 5.4 and i was wondering which is better to use to gen a random salt for password security?

```
$salt = sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(23));
```

or

```
$seed = '';
$a = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
$seed .= @fread($a,23);
$salt = sha1(seed);
```

or should i just go with:

```
$salt =  openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40);
```

or

```
$salt = '';
$a = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
$salt .= @fread($a,23);
```

Comment: Using `sha1()` will greatly reduce the effectiveness of your random salt since it will convert it to a string that is 40 chars and only containing 0-9 and a-f characters. There would be a lot less combinations (meaning less random) than if you just used 40 bytes from `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`

Comment: i am going with both of your suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For security purposes you are better off using `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. OpenSSL takes care of gathering enough entropy to serve you good randomness. `/dev/urandom` is devised to *never* block and could be tricked into giving you not so random bytes.

With random bytes you do not need to run them through SHA1.

To sum it all, do:

```
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(40, $cstrong);
if (! $cstrong) {
    exit('This should not happen');
}
```

Comment: Actually, `openssl_rand_pseudo_bytes` doesn't _guarantee_ true randomness either, any more than `/dev/urandom` does; that's what the `pseudo` in the name means.  In practice, however, both produce output indistinguishable from random by any known means.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Of course you do not get true randomness. I only wrote “good” ; what OpenSSL calls “cryptographically strong”. That is why I put in the test to check that the result is cryptographically strong.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski what do you suggest as an alternative? AFAIK `/dev/urandom` also has problems if used incorrectly. Also, the issue you linked to only applies to certain server configurations and has been fixed in the latest release of PHP. I prefer to use something that has been tested and any problems sorted out, and avoid switching to an alternative with unknown problems.

Comment: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat - which is a PHP 5 polyfill for PHP 7's secure `random_bytes()` function.

Answer (score 10):

In practice, there is almost certainly no difference.

Both [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) and `/dev/urandom` provide a cryptographically secure source of pseudorandom bytes.  Neither is guaranteed to be *truly* random, but in practice, both are expected to be indistinguishable from true randomness by any known or foreseeable techniques.

Kmkaplan is technically correct in noting that `/dev/urandom` could return theoretically predictable output under certain conditions, as noted in [`man unrandom`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom):

> "A read from the */dev/urandom* device will not block waiting for more entropy. As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver. Knowledge of how to do this is not available in the current unclassified literature, but it is theoretically possible that such an attack may exist. If this is a concern in your application, use */dev/random* instead."

However, the same is actually true of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` (which [calls](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c) the OpenSSL function `RAND_pseudo_bytes` internally), as noted in the [OpenSSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_bytes.html):

> "`RAND_pseudo_bytes()` puts **num** pseudo-random bytes into **buf**. Pseudo-random byte sequences generated by `RAND_pseudo_bytes()` will be unique if they are of sufficient length, but are not necessarily unpredictable. They can be used for non-cryptographic purposes and for certain purposes in cryptographic protocols, but usually not for key generation etc."

Neither of these warnings should actually scare you from using these methods — the weaknesses they describe are only theoretical, except possibly under certain contrived circumstances (such as on a diskless embedded device with no hardware RNG immediately after boot-up), and should not be of practical concern in situations where PHP is normally deployed.

The upshot is, neither of these random number generation methods is going to be [the weakest link](https://buildsecurityin.us-cert.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/principles/356-BSI.html) in your cryptosystem, so you can safely choose either one.  If you're feeling paranoid, you could even use both.

---

Ps. One advantage of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is that it works on Windows, too.  On the other hand, `/dev/urandom` is available on Unix even if the OpenSSL PHP extension is not installed.  Thus, for maximum portability, you should indeed implement support for both.

Also, always check that you indeed received as many bytes as you expected; for example, the `/dev/urandom` based code in your question above could silently return an empty string on systems like Windows where `/dev/urandom` does not exist.

Comment: `RAND_pseudo_bytes` and `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` returns a code that tells you “if the bytes generated are cryptographically strong”.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but if anyone stumbles into this here is an easy solution:

compat_random.php
https://gist.github.com/anzz1/29a787fac8ef6d693b41779911287505

```
<?php
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/compat_random.php');

  $salt = random_bytes(40);
?>
```

Done.

The compat_random.php is only 2KB, 62 lines of code.
You should be able to use it with any PHP version.

It checks for these functions in this order:

- random_bytes (PHP >= 7) [Cryptographically secure]
- openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (OpenSSL) [Cryptographically secure]
- mcrypt_create_iv (php_mcrypt) [Cryptographically secure]
- /dev/urandom (UNIX systems) [Cryptographically secure]

It's very likely you do have one of these available, but if you do not, it will fall finally fall back to

- mt_rand() (PHP >= 4) [Not cryptographically secure, but fine for most cases]
- rand() [Insecure]