# Why does this code hash null?

Tags: php, forms, post, passwords, sha256

The following code passes on the username check, but fails on the password.

As you can see, the hashes are echoed, but for some reason, they output `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`, which is the `sha256sum` of `/dev/null`. As the password does not seem to echo at all, i can only assume it cannot get the POST, but why?

#### login

```
<form action="dologin" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

#### dologin

```
    if ( $_POST[username] == $actualusername ) {
        // Hash the password
        $hashedpassword = hash('sha256', $_POST[password]);
        echo $_POST[password];
        echo $hashedpassword;
        if ( $hashedpassword == $actualpassword ) {
            echo '<h2>Logged in</h2>';
        } else {
        echo '<h2>Incorrect password</h2>';
        echo $hashedpassword;
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Incorrect username</h2>';
    }
```

Comment: you should not be using the SHA* family for hashing passwords. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922395/1698924) and [Jeff's Post on Passwords](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: Please do `$_POST['password']` instead of `[password]`, as well.

Comment: @Gargron [Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922840/what-is-the-difference-in-using-quotes-apostrophes-or-neither-in-post-variabl)

Comment: @LewisGoddard - Because it can cause a very nasty and hard to find bug, should another developer or an external library define a constant named `password` somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does closing the input tags solve you problem?
Also, you can use

```
isset($_POST["blabla"])
```

To test if the value is set in `$_POST`.

Comment: Yes it does! I thought HTML5 meant you didn't need to close things like link, meta, img and input items? What a peculiar quirk.