# What is the difference in using quotes, apostrophes or neither in $_POST variables?

Tags: php, post

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922624/why-does-this-code-hash-null) in which the code did not work, and was suggested i add apostrophes to my $_POST variables.

#### I was using

```
$_POST[variable]
```

#### People (?) Recommend

```
$_POST['variable']
```

[PHP.net Recommends](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

```
$_POST["variable"]
```

What do you use, and why?
What differences arise when using one of the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no substantial difference between using `"` and `'`. Array keys can be either integers or strings. Strings are quoted in PHP. Not using quotes in this case works, but PHP checks if the key is a constant first, then falling back on interpreting it as a string. Not quoting array keys is [discouraged in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts).

Answer (score 1):

The first method will throw a Notice:

```
[18-Feb-2013 02:46:06] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant variable - assumed 'variable' in /Users/Aram/Development/Web/test.php on line 6
```

Also, you can't have hyphens, as it will treat them separately.

```
[18-Feb-2013 02:46:56] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant variable - assumed 'variable' in /Users/Aram/Development/Web/test.php on line 6
[18-Feb-2013 02:46:56] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in /Users/Aram/Development/Web/test.php on line 6
```

Use single quotes, since it's simpler than double quotes and doesn't require the use of the shift key.

Answer (score 1):

It is not about $_POST variables.
It is about **strings**.
Strings as **array keys** to be strict.

You have strings as array keys here - so, you have to format them as strings.
To format strings, you can use whatever quotes, no difference.

`variable` without quotes is actually a **constant**.

The only case where you have to omit quotes is a double-quoted string:

```
echo "Hello $_GET[name], howdy?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST[variable]` if `variable` is the name of a Constant, or a variable: $var.

Use `$_POST["variable"]` or `$_POST['variable'] if`variable` is a string.