# Is there an advantage to this hash for security?

Tags: php, security, hash, sha1

Is there any advantage to

```
sha1(sha1(sha1($password. $salt)));
```

Basically having multiple sha1 verses just one sha1

```
sha1($password. $salt);
```

Comment: if your `$salt` is strong, longer and a random mix of characters, the later should suffice. basically, the later is only vulnerable if someone has compiled rainbow tables with your salt, which is next to none, if your `$salt` is strong enough, e.g. `12@!(*E&HD*&@#HE!_)UDJNuyhdsbq897cuddaadn*&BD#NXUHSD8uyahs`... using multiple `sha1` is just a bit more secure in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using a strong salt.

Comment: Related Question with some good information and conversation: [Many Hash Iterations, append salt every time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not, I repeat, **DO NOT** attempt to make your password hash safer by doing "special" things do your hash.

First of all, `sha1(sha1(sha1($input)))` only has for side effect to **increase the chance of collision**<sup>*</sup> on each iteration. Increasing the chance of collisions is a very bad thing.

Instead of trying your hand at do-it-yourself cryptology, why not trust libraries made by actual experts in the field? Use the [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

PHPass actually uses **bcrypt**, which is an algorithm designed to prevent rainbow table, dictionary and brute force attacks. You can initialize it with a number of rounds: the higher the rounds, the longer it takes to compute the hash. That way, you can create stronger hashes if processing power increases.

---

<sup>*</sup> The first call to `sha1()` takes infinite input and creates one out of `2`<sup>`160`</sup> outputs. The second iteration takes `2`<sup>`160`</sup> inputs and creates one out of `x` outputs, where `x <= 2`<sup>`160`</sup>. The third iteration takes `x` input and creates one out of `y` outputs, where `y <= x <= 2`<sup>`160`</sup>.

Why does each call to `sha1()` reduces the amount of possible outputs? Because the algorithm behind `sha1()` was not designed for one-to-one matching of the hashes. Theoretically, you are bound to have collisions if you were to hash every possible hash.

Comment: phpAss itself hashes using multiple iterations (just take a peek at the very first method), this is a good security practice.

Comment: @Alex Axel: In portable mode, yes it does. BUT, it always rehashes the previous hash concatenated with the password ( `sha1($hash . $password)` ), keeping possible inputs to infinite therefore not increasing the chance of collision... Usually, `$password` is the only source of infinite input unless you are using a per-hash `$salt`.

Comment: @Andrew Moore: There is a fallacy in your argument, bcrypt has *similar* chances of collisions as sha1 - both are rehashed multiple times.

Comment: @Alix: no.  calling `sha1(...sha1($f00))` will have a degenerating number of collisions.  To see why, let's name it `A(B(C($foo)))`.  Now, we know `C` will have collisions since infinity > 2^256.  So all collisions for `C` automatically become collisions for both A and `B` since the input isn't modified.  The same goes for `B and `A`.  So the total collisions are much more than for `C` alone.  But, if you did `A(B(C($foo) . $foo) . $foo)`, it'd have the exact same number of collisions as `C`...

Comment: @Alix Axel: `bcrypt` does not actually iterate any transformation on the password. `bcrypt` iterates over an initialization vector transforming it multiple times in order to create an hash using the resulting vector. In basic terms, it transforms a "salt" (IV) multiple times until it is cryptographically secure enough to generate an hash using it. To compare an input to a bcrypt hash, you need the stored hash in order to extract the original IV (stored within the hash, unique to each), let `bcrypt` transform the vector again, hash the raw input, and compare the two resulting hashes.

Comment: **COMMENT EDIT:** Actually, after revising the `bcrypt` spec, it uses both the IV and the input to generate sub-keys... Not that it affects its chances of collisions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called [key strengthening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening) (but is normally done thousands of times) and the salt should be appended on every iteration for better entropy:

```
$hash = sha1($password . $salt);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 65000; ++$i)
{
    $hash = sha1($hash . $salt);
}
```

Also, [read this awesome blog post](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html) - or at least this short quote:

> The better you can optimize your
>   password hash function, the faster
>   your password hash function gets, the
>   weaker your scheme is. MD5 and SHA1,
>   even conventional block ciphers like
>   DES, are designed to be fast. MD5,
>   SHA1, and DES are weak password
>   hashes. On modern CPUs, raw crypto
>   building blocks like DES and MD5 can
>   be bitsliced, vectorized, and
>   parallelized to make password searches
>   lightning fast. Game-over FPGA
>   implementations cost only hundreds of
>   dollars.
>
> **Using raw hash functions to authenticate passwords is as naive as
>   using unsalted hash functions.
>   Don’t.**
>
> What is the state of the art here?
>
> First, what your operating system
>   already gives you: a password scheme
>   “optimized” to be computationally
>   expensive. The most famous of these is
>   PHK’s FreeBSD MD5 scheme.
>
> The difference between PHK’s scheme
>   and the one you were about to use for
>   your social shopping cart 2.0
>   application is simple. You were just
>   going to run MD5 on a salt and a
>   password and store the hash. **PHK
>   runs MD5 for thousands of iterations.
>   That’s called “stretching”.**

Comment: Always re-introduce as much information into each hash cycle as possible.  I'd suggest adding the password to the inner `sha1` call as well.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time/3559497#3559497) for more information.  Also see the [PBKDF2 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) for key-stretching

Comment: Don't use `sha1($hash . $salt)` unless `$salt` changes on every hash generation. If it doesn't, you are increasing your chances of collisions for the same reason stated in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742891/is-there-an-advantage-to-this-hash-for-security/4743025#4743025).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. When you chain two hash algorithms, all you're doing is creating another hash algorithm that has unknown properties (security-wise). Use a salt (or even better, HMAC).

Answer (score 0):

The more times it has to go through the hashing process, the longer it takes to hash, and the fewer attempts an attacker will get per day.  If hashing it once takes 10ms, and hashing it a ten times takes 100ms, then an attacker can attempt 6000 passwords per minute with hashing it once, and 600 per minute with hashing it ten times.  Of course, with a web application, trying to brute force at either 6000 or 600 per minute is essentially a DOS attack.  Cryptographic hashes tend to take a while to do for this purpose, and it's also common to hash multiple times.

You should probably use sha512 instead of sha1, which you can do with `hash()` like `hash('sha512',$stringtobehashed);`, sha512 also takes approximately 5 times longer than sha1 to hash.

Comment: That's assuming that it's running on one core with no parallelism.  It could in theory be running on many cores (12 core systems are common, with GPUs having tons more).  Not to mention that more than one hash can be run at a time using pipelining, so the real number is likely far higher than 6k passwords per minute (I'd be surprised if a decent piece of hardware couldn't hit 100k per minute or more)...