# Update old stored md5 passwords in PHP to increase security

Tags: php, security, encryption, hash, passwords

At the moment I have a database with md5 passwords stored, a few years back this was considered a little more secure than it is now and it's got to the point where the passwords need to be more secure.

I've read a lot of posts on here about `crypt`, `md5`, `hash`, `bcrypt`, etc and have come to consider using something along the lines of the following to 'secure' the passwords better than they are now.

I will use a combination of `hash("sha512"` and two salts, the first salt will be a site wide salt stored in a file such as .htaccess and the second salt will be created for each user.

Here's an example **along the lines** of what I'm testing at the moment:

.htaccess

```
SetEnv SITEWIDE_SALT NeZa5Edabex?26Y#j5pr7VASpu$8UheVaREj$yA*59t*A$EdRUqer_prazepreTr
```

example.php

```
$currentpassword = //get password

$pepper = getenv('SITEWIDE_SALT');
$salt = microtime().ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$saltpepper = $salt.$pepper;

$password = hash("sha512", md5($currentpassword).$saltpepper);
```

The salt would obviously need to be stored in a separate table to allow checking of future inserted login passwords but it would never be possible for a user to see. Do you think this is a sufficient way to go about this?

Comment: plain SHA512 is still a bad idea. Use PBKDF2 or bcrypt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, let's go over a few points here

1. What you have in `$salt` is not a salt.  It's deterministic (meaning that there is no randomness in there at all).  If you want a salt, use either [`mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) or some other source of actual random entropy.  The point is that it should be both unique and random.  Note that it doesn't need to be cryptographically secure random...  At absolute worst, I'd do something like this:

   ```
   function getRandomBytes($length) {
       $bytes = '';
       for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
           $bytes .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
       }
       return $bytes;
   }
   ```
2. As @Anony-Mousse indicated, **never** feed the output of one hash function into another without re-appending the original data back to it.  Instead, use a proper iterative algorithm such as [PBKDF2](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/lib/CryptLib/Key/Derivation/PBKDF/PBKDF2.php#L45), [PHPASS](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) or [CRYPT_BLOWFISH](http://us.php.net/crypt) ($2a$).

My suggestion would be to use `crypt` with blowfish, as it's the best available for PHP at this time:

```
    function createBlowfishHash($password) {
        $salt = to64(getRandomBytes(16));
        $salt = '$2a$10$' . $salt;
        $result = crypt($password, $salt);
    }
```

And then verify using a method like this:

```
    function verifyBlowfishHash($password, $hash) {
        return $hash == crypt($password, $hash);
    }

(note that `to64` is a good method defined [here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-CryptLib/blob/master/lib/CryptLib/Password/Implementation/Blowfish.php#L149)).  You could also use `str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode($salt));`...
```

I'd also suggest you read the following two:

- [Fundamental difference between hashing and encrypting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393)
- [Many hash iterations, append salt every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559437/many-hash-iterations-append-salt-every-time/3559497#3559497)

### Edit: To Answer the Migration Question

Ok, so I realize that my answer did not address the migration aspect of the original question.  So here's how I would solve it.

First, build a temporary function to create a new blowfish hash from the original md5 hash, with a random salt and a prefix so that we can detect this later:

```
function migrateMD5Password($md5Hash) {
    $salt = to64(getRandomBytes(16));
    $salt = '$2a$10$' . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($md5Hash, $salt);
    return '$md5' . $hash;
}
```

Now, run all the existing md5 hashes through this function and save the result in the database.  We put our own prefix in so that we can detect the original password and add the additional md5 step.  So now we're all migrated.

Next, create another function to verify passwords, and if necessary update the database with a new hash:

```
function checkAndMigrateHash($password, $hash) {
    if (substr($hash, 0, 4) == '$md5') {
        // Migrate!
        $hash = substr($hash, 4);
        if (!verifyBlowfishHash(md5($password), $hash) {
            return false;
        }
        // valid hash, so let's generate a new one
        $newHash = createBlowfishHash($password);
        saveUpdatedPasswordHash($newHash);
        return true;
    } else {
        return verifyBlowfishHash($password, $hash);
    }
}
```

This is what I would suggest for a few reasons:

1. It gets the `md5()` hashes out of your database immediately.
2. It eventually (next login for each user) updates the hash to a better alternative (one that's well understood).
3. It's pretty easy to follow in code.

To answer the comments:

1. **A salt doesn't need to be random** - I direct you to [RFC 2898 - Password Based Cryptography](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt).  Namely, Section 4.1.  And I quote:

> If there is no concern about interactions between multiple uses
> of the same key (or a prefix of that key) with the password-
> based encryption and authentication techniques supported for a
> given password, then the salt may be generated at random and
> need not be checked for a particular format by the party
> receiving the salt. It should be at least eight octets (64
> bits) long.

Additionally,

> Note. If a random number generator or pseudorandom generator is not
> available, a deterministic alternative for generating the salt (or
> the random part of it) is to apply a password-based key derivation
> function to the password and the message M to be processed.

A PseudoRandom Generator is available, so why not use it?

2. **Is your solution the same as bcrypt? I can't find much documentation on what bcrypt actually is?**  - I'll assume that you already read the [bcrypt Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), and try to explain it better.

BCrypt is based off the Blowfish block cipher.  It takes the key schedule setup algorithm from the cipher, and uses that to hash the passwords.  The reason that it is good, is that the setup algorithm for Blowfish is designed to be very expensive (which is part of what makes blowfish so strong of a cypher).  The basic process is as follows:

1. A 18 element array (called P boxes, 32 bits in size) and 4 2-dimensional arrays (called S boxes, each with 256 entries of 8 bits each) are used to setup the schedule by initializing the arrays with predetermined static values.  Additionally, a 64 bit state is initialized to all 0's.
2. The key passed in is XOred with all 18 P boxes in order (rotating the key if it's too short).
3. The P boxes are then used to encrypt the state that was previously initialized.
4. The ciphertext produced by step 3 is used to replace P1 and P2 (the first 2 elements of the P array).
5. Step 3 is repeated, and the result is put in P3 and P4. This continues until P17 and P18 are populated.

That's the key derivation from the Blowfish Cipher.  BCrypt modifies that to this:

1. The 64 bit state is initialized to *an encrypted version of the salt*.
2. Same
3. The P boxes are then used to encrypt the (state *xor part of the salt*) that was previously initialized.
4. Same
5. Same
6. The resulting setup is then used to encrypt the password 64 times.  That's what's returned by BCrypt.

The point is simple:  It's a very expensive algorithm that takes a lot of CPU time.  That's the real reason that it should be used.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: A salt doesn't need to be random.

Comment: What alternative migration path from md5 do suggest, if you want to avoid chaining hash functions? The original data isn't available.

Comment: Is your solution the same as bcrypt? I can't find much documentation on what bcrypt actually is?

Comment: This description still feels like a hack and not a clean, well-designed, solution. I don't mean to knock it, but you'd be better off getting these accounts transitions from the old system to a new, clean, bcrypt or PBKDF2, solution that uses that and only that as it's a well tested and well designed solution. See my answer for a plan on how to do this, as you CAN transition accounts over to a fundamentally clean and secure system.

Comment: And bcrypt is just a way of taking a password and coming up with a hash-like value but it's more secure/resistant-to-attack than just hashing something. Good description here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt.

Comment: What's the best `bcrypt` example to look at?

Comment: @CodeInChaos and Silver89 - I've answered your points in an edit to the answer.  Please review.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not nest `md5` inside your `sha512` hash**. An `md5` collision then implies a hash collision in the outer hash, too (because you are hashing the same values!)

The common way of storing passwords is to use a scheme such as

```
<method><separator><salt><separator><hash>
```

When validating the password, you read `<method>` and `<salt>` from this field, reapply them to the password, and then check that it produces the same `<hash>`.

Check the `crypt` functions you have available. On a modern Linux system, `crypt` should be able to use `sha512` password hashing in a sane way: [PHP crypt manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php). **Do not reinvent the wheel**, you probably just screw up more badly than `md5`, unless you are an expert on cryptographic hashing. It will even take care of above scheme: the Linux standard is to use `$` as separator, and `$6$` is the method ID for `sha512`, while `$2a$` indicates you want to use `blowfish`. So you can even have multiple hashes in use in your database. `md5` hashes are prefixed with `$1$<salt>$` (unless you reinvented md5 hashing, then your hashes may be incompatible).

Seriously, reuse the existing `crypt` function. It is well checked by experts, extensible, and compatible across many applications.

Comment: Collisions are irrelevant for password hashing. The relevant attack is pre-image, and I see no immediate weaknesses in that scenario when chainging hash functions.

Comment: And inputing md5 into a good password hashing function is the best migration path IMO. It's certainly better than keeping md5 hashes around.

Comment: Assuming that the `md5` values of the original passwords had been leaked, any collision will then still be accepted as a password. Just rehash with a stronger hash. sha-512-of-md5 is only acceptable if this is for not-yet-reset-md5-passwords. But then, the `md5` does not need to be recomputed as in his code.

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of your new, more secure, password storage should use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), as that's really the best solution out there right now.

Don't nest things, as you don't get any real security out of this due to collisions as @Anony-Mousse describes.

What you may want to do it implement a "transition routine" where your app transitions users over from the old MD5-based system to the new more secure system as they log in. When a login request comes in, see if the user is in the new, more secure, system. If so, bcrypt/PBKDF2 the password, compare, and you're good to go. If they are not (no one will be at first), check them using the older MD5-based system. If it matches (password is correct), perform the bcrypt/PBKDF2 transformation of the password (since you now have it), store it in the new system, and delete the old MD5 record. Next time they log in, they have an entry in the new system so you're good to go. Once all of the users have logged in once you implement this, you can remove this transition functionality and just authenticate against the new system.

Comment: +1 This is a really great description of how to actually implement a solution.  I hope this gets a lot of upvotes.  It's just the kind of SO answer I love to see!

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this subject a while back and found the following link of great use:

[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

I also use the following to create a random salt:

```
public static function getRandomString($length = 20) {
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $string .= substr($characters, (mt_rand() % strlen($characters)), 1);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is literally wrong and misleading.  The simple quote: *Yes, there are crypt and bcrypt but I do not trust them.* shows a major misunderstanding in how they work and the general concepts related to password security.  It's really a shame that popular != good.