# What is the best method to encrypt password in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, encryption

Can anyone help me out to find the best encryption method for codeigniter?

Comment: why dont you use md5 or sha1 of php. They can be used in Codeigniter

Comment: @Raheel: md5 is not secure. It can be cracked

Answer (score 3):

hi you can use md5 php function to encryt password string while login you have to check hash of string with hash saved in database there is one good post for password encryption you can read that

[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329999/php-encrypting-passwords)

here are two good libraries for creating encrypted password

[PHP Password library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib)

[PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

codeigniter auth library like tank auth using PHPass for encrypting password

Comment: Do not use MD5 for password hashing; md5 is now (or should be) officially useless for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use SHA1 with some static salt concatenated to it.

Answer (score 1):

In few months a new php password API will be available.

https://gist.github.com/3707231

Its greatest advantage is that it hugely simplifies existing hashing APIs while still maintaining a high level of security.

Answer (score 0):

Use password_compat from github.

Implements the new PHP 5.5 password hasing logic but you can use it now for older PHP versions

Link: [GITHUB PASSWORD_COMPAT](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)