# php "else" code redirecting instead of echo-ing

Tags: php, mysql

Just trying to make a login page in php.. Here the if code is working but else code is not working.. it is also working if code.. instead of printing message..
here is the code:

```
session_start();  //session starts
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');// connecting to ..........
mysql_select_db('news_db'); //connectin to db
if(isset($_POST['login'])) //if button login is pressed
{
    $name=$_REQUEST['username'];//getting name
    $password=$_REQUEST['password'];   //getting password
    $qyer=mysql_query("select * from news_tb where username='$name' and password='$password'"); //selecting fields
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($qyer); //fetching values in row
    if($row['username']==$name && $row['password']==$password)// condition to match the fields with database
    {   

        header("location:news1.php");  // on else also this page is opening
    }
    else
    {
        echo "pls enter valid information";    //redirects to if condition and doesnt print the msg
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What works and what doesnt work??

Comment: Indent your code. It makes it easier to spot mistakes in blocks of code.

Comment: Anyway, with that kind of problem, the reason is never "else doesn't do what it is supposed to do" , but "else is actually never hit". Try to find why your if condition is always true...

Comment: If you're new to this, I'd suggest looking into a good ORM (object relational mapping) library, like RedBeanPHP (redbeanphp.com).

Comment: Unrelated, you should store your passwords encrypted. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329999/php-encrypting-passwords

Comment: This can easily be solved by just looking at the `$_REQUEST` and `$row` variables. Those are the variables used in the `if` statement. Use the `var_dump` function to see what is in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Its because by pressing send or whatever, you post the code to the script. All you are doing is checking if it has been posted, not if the variables themselves are empty. Then if you have an empty row in mySQL, you will never use the else.