# how to update data in mysql without update image first

Tags: php, mysql, image, edit

I want to update my data in mysql.
But, if i want update (ex. firstname), photo_profile will lost.

```
 <?php
    include 'function_page_user.php';

    if(($_FILES['photo_profile']) and ($_POST['firstname']) and ($_POST['lastname']) and ($_POST['password']))
    {
        session_start();

        include 'connect.php';
        $foldername="assets/img/user/";
        $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstname"]);
        $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastname"]);
        $pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

        if((!empty($firstname) and !empty($lastname) and !empty($pwd)) and($_FILES['photo_profile']))
        {
            $image = $foldername . basename ($_FILES['photo_profile'] ['name']);
            mysql_query ("update user set firstname = '".$firstname."' , lastname = '".$lastname."' , password = '".$pwd."' , photo_profile='".$image."' where id_user ='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_profile']['tmp_name'], $image);
            echo "<script>alert ('File Succes To edit');</script>";
            $page="formubahuser.php";

            echo redirectPage($page);   
        }
        else echo "variabel empty";
    }
    else 
        echo ("your data is not complete<a href=formubahuser.php>Fill it again</a>");
?>
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusing series of edits. Was trying to review edits with a toddler on my lap.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of major problems in your code. Before you continue, you need to read about the following topics:

1) The php `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. That means the functions will be removed in future versions of php. You should use [pdo](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) instead

2) When you store passwords in your database, they should always, always, always be **[encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329999/php-encrypting-passwords)**.

Regarding your question, I think you are asking how to change the metadata (such as a firstname) without unsetting the photo url. Try something like this:

```
$updatequery = "UPDATE user SET firstname = '".$firstname."' , lastname = '".$lastname."' , password = '".$pwd."'";
if( $_FILES['photo_profile'])
{ 
   $image = $foldername . basename ($_FILES['photo_profile'] ['name']);
   $updatequery .= ", photo_profile='".$image."'"; 
}
$updatequery .= " where id_user ='".$_SESSION['id']."'";
```